# Linux Server/Python: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, linux

I've tried writing a program in Python which takes some values, makes a directory and adds it to a text file for later use. I've uploaded it to an ubuntu VPS server as I intend to use it at a later date with my website. However, whenever I run the code (below) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fileCreator.py", line 13, in <module>
    os.mkdir(dirName)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'just-a-test'
```

Python Code:

```
#!/usr/src
import os
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
import sys

title = raw_input("Blog Title: ")
dirName = title.replace(" ", "-").lower()

if os.path.isdir(dirName):
    print("Error: Directory Exists")
    sys.exit()
else:
    os.mkdir(dirName)

copy_tree("page", dirName)

def assignment(title, dirName ):
    desc = raw_input("Article Description: ")

    fo = open(dirName + "/txt-files/title.txt", "w")
    fo.write(title)
    fo.close()

    fo = open(dirName + "/txt-files/desc.txt", "w")
    fo.write(desc)
    fo.close()

    return None

assignment(title, dirName)
print("Done")
```

It's some sort of permission error and I've seen a few other topics on it but none of them have resulted in a solution. I'm not overly proficient with Linux commands, so bare with! Would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Print the current working directory for debugging. `os.getcwd()`

Comment: Reduce your problem/code to managing filesystem resources in restricted environments. Learn from related questions with answers.

Comment: @SaschaGottfried What do you mean?

Comment: @harandk I know which directory it works in, but I don't know how to fix the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR; run `chmod 744` in the directory with your Python script.

You don't have the correct permissions for the directory in which you are attempting to create the folder. From the same directory where you have fileCreator.py, run `ls -la .` on the command line and it will output something like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x   9 user  staff   306 Oct  9 21:29 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 36 user  staff  1224 Sep 28 12:26 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   977 Oct  9 21:04 .bashrc
```

And probably a bunch of other files. The first line is the current directory. `user` is your login and `staff` is the group that owns it. They will be different on your system. The `drwxr-xr-x` is the permissions, and they are changed by the `chmod` command.

Check out more about Linux permissions here: https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: Ah this is brilliant, thanks. I previously tried checking the directory users to see if that would change anything but the 744 works so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def create_assignment_directory(path):
    """
    create given path in local filesystem
    given path can be a relative, absolute path or
    path using tilde symbols like '~/folder_in_home_directory'

    prints absolute, normalized path for debugging purposes     
    """
    expanded_path = os.path.expanduser(path)
    normalized_path = os.path.abspath(expanded_path)

    print("create directory {0}".format(normalized_path))
    try:
        os.mkdir(expanded_path)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == 17:  # errno.EEXIST
            print("directory {0} already exists.".format(normalized_path))
    else:
        print("successfully created directory {0}".format(normalized_path))

print("current working directory {0}".format(os.getcwd()))
create_assignment_directory("just-a-test")
create_assignment_directory("~/just-a-test")
create_assignment_directory("/tmp/just-a-test")
```